# Are the situation of a man in an obscured freely falling ship in a uniform gravity field and a man in such a ship in deep space equivalent?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, time

Suppose a man finds himself in a spaceship in which he can't see anything that happens outside.

And imagine his ship is falling in a uniform gravitational field. For a *truly* uniform gravitational field see [this](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath530/kmath530.htm) article, where it's made clear (and as might be expected) that such a field can be produced by an infinite massive plane or by a massive shell (with a constant mass density) with infinite radius which has on the "outside" gravitation that's two times as great (as might be expected) as the infinite plane and on the "inside" (the other side of the plane) zero gravitation.

Let's consider the shell. The force of gravity on one side is $\vec{F}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial r}=C$. This means $U=Cr+c=Cr$ when we set $c=0$, which implies the potential is also zero on the non-gravity side. So far the classical part.

When we include GR, time on the gravity side runs at a slower pace as you get "deeper" in the uniform field. The freely falling man in the obscured ship though doesn't know he's falling. For him, he could as well be on the other side of the plane where gravity is zero. As far as the man on the other side with no gravity is concerned, he could think he falls freely in a uniform gravity field.

Aren't both situations equivalent and as such will time for both men be equally dilated? But then again doesn't this contradict the fact that the man in the uniform field experiences different paces of time while falling? Is this a paradox?

The next equality holds:

$$d \tau = \sqrt{ 1 + \frac{2 \Phi}{c^2}} dt,$$

If

$$U=Cr=\Phi,$$

then, after putting this in the equation for $d\tau$, we get:

$$d \tau = \sqrt{ 1 + \frac{2 Cr}{c^2}} dt,$$

so the higher you climb in the uniform gravitation field (making $r$ bigger), the faster the pace of $d\tau$ will be. So if $r$ approaches infinity, $d\tau$ will approach a pace that is an infinite time faster than the pace of $dt$ (on the plane, or anywhere at a finite height above the plane).

So seen from infinity, it seems the time on the plane's surface (or at any point at a finite height above the plane) has come to a full stop. This seems reasonable because a photon traveling away from the plane will acquire an infinite wavelength and the plane (or, again, any point at a finite height above the plane) has because of that disappeared from sight at infinity. The plane behaves as a "black plane". The infinite plane (or another plane at a finite height above the plane) has become a horizon (though on the horizon life runs at a normal pace, as it is everywhere in the uniform field). Even at infinity life runs at the same pace as everywhere else in the uniform field.

Comment: 1. I do not understand how a "massive ball with infinite radius" is supposed to be a well-defined geometry. Infinite planes are perfectly fine mathematical objects, balls with infinite radius are not. 2. "Time has a slower pace [...]" is a nonsensical statement as it lacks a reference frame. The passage of time can always only be dilated compared to some other frame.

Comment: 1) Why isn't a ball with an infinite radius a well-defined geometry? It's just an infinite plane with different gravitational properties on both sides. 2)Why is that a nonsensical statement? Isn't it true that the deeper you go in a gravity field (in the direction of the force), the pace of time slows down? What other frame did you (for example) have in mind? A frame with a constant velocity moving through the uniform gravity field?

Comment: Gravitational properties aren't something you get to define - the matter/energy distribution fixes them through the Einstein equations. If it is "just an infinite plane" geometrically then it must have precisely the same gravitational characteristics as an infinite plane.

Comment: So you don't agree with the article I made a link to?

Comment: Why can't you make the GR calculations for a ball with radius $R$, see how spacetime is affected and take the limit for $R$ (to infinity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greater the gravitational poential, the less time is dilated, whether you are in freefall or not. Time would seem to pass normally for each man in their own reference frame.

Comment: The gravitational field is everywhere the same. But then again that would imply a flat spacetime. Thanks to your question I suddenly realized the mistake I made! So +1 and accepted!

Comment: Gravitational time dilation is not proportional to the gravitational field, it is proportional to the gravitational potential.

Answer (score 4):

> For a truly uniform gravitational field see this article

I don’t think that I would describe the result on that page as “truly uniform”. That is the exterior field of a fixed density spherical shell as the radius goes to infinity. As such it has curvature everywhere which goes to zero in the limit.

> Aren't both situations equivalent and as such will time for both men walk at the same pace?

All *local* experiments will yield identical results for both the inside and outside free fall observers. This is the meaning of the equivalence principle.

> But then again doesn't this contradict the fact that the man in the uniform field experiences different paces of time while falling? Is this a paradox?

No, this is not a paradox. Comparing the times of the two observers is inherently a non-local experiment. The equivalence principle simply does not apply.

Comment: The mass density of ball with a radius going to infinity stays of course the same (I edited). Are you saying the time for the falling man walks at a slower pace than that of the man on the zero-gravity side of the plane? I.e. if they perform the non-local experiment of meeting each other? Or how do you a envision non-local experiment?

Comment: I would assume that they send signals through the mass shell (make it transparent). The observer inside the shell is at a lower potential so his time is slower.

Comment: So it's indeed the potential, as I already wrote at the end of my question, that determines the pace of time in a small and uniform gravity field.

Comment: Yes, for any spacetime that has a gravitational potential the gravitational time dilation between two observers is due to the difference in potential. Note, not all spacetimes have a potential. For those time dilation cannot usually be cleanly separated into a gravitational and a kinematic part.

Comment: Can you give an example of spacetime without a potential?

Comment: I do think that an infinite plane is uniform. I do not think that a spherical shell is, even in the limit. The FLRW spacetime of cosmology does not have a potential

Comment: So you don't agree with what is written in the article (concerning the ball with radius reaching for infinity)?

Comment: The article goes back and forth contradicting and changing its claims repeatedly, so I don’t even know what agreeing with that article would mean. I found it exceptionally confusing and unconvincing

Comment: Time runs at a certain pace at both bottoms of the infinite plane and the potential grows linearly with the distance $r$ from both bottoms. The difference in potential between two points vertically aligned above (or below) the plane, say with a difference of $1m$, is always $C$, no matter how high the points lie. So if you go up $1m$ time goes faster, if you go up again $1m$ then this new faster pace of time goes faster by the same amount (correct me if I'm wrong), etc. to infinity. What is the pace of time at infinity? Does it seem there time on the plane has stopped? Does a horizon develop?

Comment: This is an edit of a former comment, which I deleted because I see what you mean now. Why don't you think that the gravity fields on both sides of a ball with a radius approaching infinity plane are truly uniform? The mass density of the ball stays the same.

Comment: What is the adjective “truly” supposed to mean there? To me a limit of a curved space is not “truly” a flat space, and the paper wasn’t terribly convincing to the contrary. To me a “truly” flat spacetime would be flat, not just flat in some limit.

Comment: By a truly uniform field, I mean it's not approximately uniform (as it is for example on the surface of the Earth). The gravitational field vectors are identical *everywhere* (on both sides of the plate). In the case of the ball, the surface has a constant mass density, regardless of how big it gets, just as the infinite plane has a constant mass density everywhere. The mass of the ball doesn't stay constant but grows linearly with $R^2$. So the field on the inside stays zero (like in a massive shell), while the field on the "outside" is twice as big as on both sides of the infinite plane.

Comment: So then this would not be truly uniform as it is a limit of a curved spacetime and looking everywhere (as you mentioned) would include looking at large distances, including at distances that grow faster than R.

Comment: What do you mean with "distances that grow faster than R"? Wherever you look or stay in the spacetime below or above the plate, the gravity is the same. Or not?

Comment: I am talking about the spherical shell, not the plate.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. R is already assumed to be infinite. And besides, growing distances correspond to velocity. You can't compare velocity with a distance (in this case R, however great it is). Do you see what I mean?

Comment: If you are talking about a spherical shell then there is always some distance over which there is curvature. So it is not uniform **everywhere** as you required

Comment: Except for the case that R is infinite (or approaches infinite, but can you explain the difference?).

Comment: In which case the spacetime is asymptotically (or in fact) flat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102663/discussion-between-dale-and-descheleschilder).